# display external text from txt, html etc. (hosted on cloud) on web page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I manage a small web page for a relative's business. They want to provide notes on the page for the visitors regularly (opening times, news etc.) but cannot code the web page themselves.

Is there a way to embed a news scroller, text field, whatever on the page - however, the text displayed there then comes from an external source they can manage like a htm, txt, json (whatever) file hosted e.g. on their Google Drive that they simply need to change and see the edits directly in the web page (the file would be public; the URL to be embedded in the web page code).

Is there a solution or an easier way to achieve it? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents()` if I got you right.

Comment: thanks to all of you for comments. However, do you have working jsfiddle example for that where it works. I saw some examples but all of those I saw do not work with public txt files. And even more so: how to get a direct url from a private cloud. AFAIK, you get a cryptic link without the exact filename attached to it, i.e. www.onedrive....sample.txt is not available. Does this work at all?

Comment: how about this and host the js file (in that example, the text is embedded in the js file) in the cloud: http://codepen.io/aamirafridi/pen/ayBmF

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, first you need to create a portion on the website to display the news or whatever external dynamic content you want.

Then you need to develop complete APIs for that site and then hit them from your website (Keep a secret key for safety). Your API can do everything you program it to do. (E.g You can put the news in database or create publicly accessible files through it)

When this is achieved, you can then fetch the data into the portion created for news etc. (automated through programming)

Using PHP you can achieve all the above mentioned steps.

That way you will just have to push/send the data from your APIs and the actual site will keep getting updated without any further action required.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If they can write the HTML and make it available at a public URL, you can simply embed it using [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in HTML.